# Key dynamic in config.yml

Tags: symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm

How can I make to a key dynamic in the config.yml
I use the vmelnik bundle, but I would like a different key for each user
I tried with a service and a tag but it does not work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a parameter dynamic.

With the Dependency Injection conponent you can customize your config parameters but only once, when the cache is warmed. So it won't be different for each user.

You can fork the bundle and edit the subscriber, in order to not use the config key, but something else, user specific ... :

https://github.com/vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Subscribers/DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php

But since user keys will be stored on the same server as the encrypted data, it won't be more secure to store your data encrypted. It is only more secure if your keys are better protected as your DB.